# Force apache common logging to use specific logger instead of SLF4J

Tags: java, apache, logging, slf4j

I have following code, which tries to disable apache common logging:

```
public class HttpMain {
  static {
    System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.log",
            "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.log",
            "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");
    Log log = LogFactory.getLog(HttpMain.class);
    log.info("You do not want to see me");
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I still see log messages, and during debugging I found that log object is actually an instance of org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog, so looks like all calls are sent to SLF4J, and handled by some SLF4J backends from maven transient dependencies.

I also tried to pass -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog as JVM parameter, but it also doesn't work..

Maybe anybody has any ideas about how to avoid this? Any way to explicitly disable common logging completely?

Thank you.

Comment: You have to ensure that no other class (which uses a Log instance) is loaded before your main class where you set the system property. Better: provide the system property as command line param (-Dtag=value) or define it directly on the OS level.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I mentioned in my post that I tried to pass JVM param, but it doesn't work..